# Maven Surefire plugin doesn't recognize -Dgroups="<my Junit5 tag>" on versions higher than 2.22.0

Tags: maven, command-line, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

I am running Java 8.
I am executing the tests from the command line as:

mvn surefire:test -Psurefire  -Dgroups="downloadWars"

WARNING] Couldn't load group class 'downloadWars' in Surefire|Failsafe plugin. The group class is ignored!

This works fine with the version set to 2.22.0. Here is the pom entry.

```
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>test</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>none</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*IntegrationTest</include>
                                </includes>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

The surefire documentation says that this should still work.
I tried 3.2.5 as specified in the documentation as well.